# Does microstrain_3dmgx2_imu work with the 3DM-GX4-25?

Tags: ros, microstrain, microstrain-3dmgx2-imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the microstrain_3dmgx2_imu driver work for the Microstrain 3DM-GX4-25?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171746/does-microstrain_3dmgx2_imu-work-with-the-3dm-gx4-25?/) by [bk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7086/bk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No.  I just tried it and get this error:

[ERROR] [1407865037.519645268]: Exception thrown while starting IMU. This sometimes happens if you are not connected to an IMU or if another process is trying to access the IMU port. You may try 'lsof|grep /dev/microstrain' to see if other processes have the port open. timeout reached (in microstrain_3dmgx2_imu::IMU:read_with_timeout) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/Troubleshooting

Apparently this library supports it:  https://github.com/KumarRobotics/imu_3dm_gx4

I haven't tried it yet, will report back when I do.

---

Originally posted by [jeff-o](https://answers.ros.org/users/11896/jeff-o/) with karma: 26 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0